# How to open .arc file

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format

I have a Contacts.arc file which took from a nokia phone as a back-up of contacts.Now my mobile is lost and i want to see some numbers.Is there any application to open .arc file in ubuntu?. I searched in google but didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be able to use [NbuExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbuexplorer/) (an open-source Windows application) to view the contents of the file.

I was able to run it in Ubuntu by installing the [Mono Visual Basic Compiler (VB.NET)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mono-vbnc) [image: Install mono-vbnc] (`sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc`) and then running `mono NbuExplorer.exe`. I don't have an `.arc` file to test this any further.

Comment: But i don't have windows..

Comment: @Abdul Please see my [updated](http://askubuntu.com/posts/43892/revisions) answer.

Comment: Hi, genius..Its worked :) :)

Answer (score 0):

`nomarch` is available for ubuntu and details is provided in 
[nomarch Ubuntu Manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/nomarch.1.html).

To install `nomarch`

```
sudo apt-get install nomarch
```

**Basic Info:**

NAME

```
   nomarch - extract ‘.arc’ archives
```

SYNOPSIS

```
   nomarch [-hlptUv] [archive.arc] [match1 [match2 ... ]]
```

DESCRIPTION

```
   nomarch  lists,  extracts,  or  tests  ‘.arc’  archives.  (An alternate
   extension sometimes used was ‘.ark’; these work too.) This  is  a  very
   outdated  file  format  which should certainly not be used for anything
   new, but you may still need an extraction utility, and here it is. :-)

   The default action is to extract all files in  the  specified  archive;
   see OPTIONS below for how to do other things instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

`nomarch` did not work for me(my file is .arc) :  `nomarch: bad first header - not a .arc file?`

`FreeArc` did : http://freearc.org/

it should work find if you are x86 (32-bit) sysytem.(check with `uname -a`)

I use x86_64(64-bit) system, which is not supported by FreeArc.

I solved the problem by running `FreeArc's Windows version` under `wine`.

Comment: my .arc file is a Windows based PC game archive